# Play: set in an apocalyptic setting

Tags: story-identification, apocalypse

I am trying to find the name of a play I remember having to read in one of my Literature classes. It is an older play and set in an apocalyptic setting (I think inside a lighthouse), there's an older guy who sits in his chair and he has a servant that I think obsesses over a clock.  The man in the chair asks what time is it, and the servant replies same as usual.

Most of the dialogue is between the two of them. There's also a couple kept in a barrel who pop up every now and then and say a few lines.

I can't think of the name of the play, but I can picture very clearly the servant walking to the window, setting down his box and looking out the window before climbing down and repeating at another window.

What is the play?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [ENDGAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endgame_%28play%29) by Samuel Beckett

> **HAMM:**
>   *One of these days I'll show them to you.*
>
> (Pause.)
>
> *It seems they've gone all white.*
>
> (Pause.)
>
> *What time is it?*
>
> **CLOV:**
>   *The same as usual.*

[English version of the text](http://samuel-beckett.net/endgame.html)

The couple in the barrel;

[image: Couple in a barrel]

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thanks!